# Adding external bluetooth antenna with U.FL connector

Tags: rf, analog, impedance, bluetooth

I want to use this [Bluetooth Module](https://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/Microchip-Technology/RN4871U-V-RM118?qs=U58vgkJzipSDEJmj2Mz0yA%3D%3D&vip=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiAzZL-BRDnARIsAPCJs700zGvJz3IqVZW0q1lpNekZVMsy6Wobq8K46V_lluUH49DysOGfAGEaAssoEALw_wcB) inside a metal casing. So I need a U.FL connector to add an external antenna. All I know, is that the trace from the pad to the connector needs to have 50 Ohms. Other than that, I have almost no knowledge of RF design.

Can the trace be lower than 50 Ohms?
Are there more requirements for the trace from pad to connector than the impedance?

Comment: I would not recommend fiddling with your own antenna traces. There are plenty of modules with u.FL on board, for example: [NORA-B100](https://www.u-blox.com/en/product/nora-b10-series), [BMD-301](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/u-blox/BMD-301-A-R/6004679), [ESP32-WROOM](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/espressif-systems/ESP32-WROOM-32UE-8MB/11613142). So, if selection of a module is not critical, I'd suggest finding one with u.FL and saving yourself a lot of troubles.

Comment: These are all way too bloated for my needs. Simple, low power Bluetooth is required

Answer (score 1):

The more "different from 50 ohms" the trace impedance is, the more power will be reflected at the impedance mismatch boundary. That *can* result in:

- less power being transmitted usefully
- less power being received usefully
- damage to your transceiver
- spurious emissions (i.e. FCC certification problems)

I would generally avoid putting any traces near the antenna trace if it can be avoided, but especially digital traces with fast edge rates as they could adversely impact the SNR.

If you've got a 4-layer board, I like to use a coplanar microstrip waveguide. There are lots of calculators available online for such a thing, for instance: https://www.changpuak.ch/electronics/Coplanar_Waveguide_Calculator.php. You just need to look up the stack-up and dielectric parameters from your PCB fabrication house and plug in numbers so that you get near 50 ohms. Just make sure you have nice solid ground planes around and below the antenna trace and you'll be fine.

Pay attention to the layout recommendations in the u.Fl connector datasheet too. They almost certainly will inform you about what the ground plane situation should be around and below the connector.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to tell the manufaturer about impedence requirements? Since there is only one signal line requiring this, are the calculations enough?

Comment: The manufacturer will tell you the nominal epsilon_r (permittivity) and a tolerance, and you can use it to see the span of possible range of impedance. For Bluetooth you are likely to do just fine without controlled impedance dieletric.